# What is the name of this number set, and what are its properties?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic states that every natural number greater than $1$ can be represented in exactly one way (apart from rearrangement) as a product of one or more primes.

So, the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, except for $1$ (and possibly for $0$, if your definition of natural number includes it), can be progressively constructed from $1$ and the prime numbers $\mathbb{P}$, *a product of primes to the power of natural numbers*, using $n=p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} \dots \, p_k^{n_k}$, where $p$'s are primes and $n$'s are natural numbers, each $n_i$ strictly smaller than $n$, obviously.

Similarly, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, except for $-1$, $0$, and $1$, can be constructed by including a minus sign to the process, $z= \pm \, p_1^{n_1} p_2^{n_2} \dots \, p_k^{n_k}$.

Now, the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ can also be constructed by such a process, with the same exceptions as above, since a rational number is defined as a fraction of integers, with non-zero denominator, by a fraction which can always be reduced to $q = \pm \, p_1^{z_1} p_2^{z_2} \dots \, p_k^{z_k}$, *a product of primes to the power of integer numbers*, where $z$'s are integers.

But what is the set we get by taking numbers that can be represented by *a product of primes to the power of rational numbers*, that is, $\pm \, p_1^{q_1} p_2^{q_2} \dots \, p_k^{q_k}$?

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand this set is not equivalent to the set of algebraic numbers, $\mathbb{A}$, so I ask:

1. Does this set has a name and symbol? Are there are references (books, articles) where I can read about this set?
2. Does this set has redundancies (equivalence classes)?
3. Does this set forms a continuum? If not, can this process, *a product of primes to the power of a product of primes to the power of ...*, be repeated a finite number of times until we get a continuum?

I think this set can be very useful not only analytically, but also numerically.

Comment: Your set is countable and therefore not a continuum. Repeating your construction finitely many times or even countably many times will not result in an uncountable set.

Comment: A product of radicals can be represented as a single radical. The factor $n$ should be the least common multiple of the denominators of $a_1, a_2 ... a_n$ .

Comment: You're correct that this is not the set of algebraic numbers. The simplest counterexample would be $1 + \sqrt{2}$, which cannot be written as the product of rational powers of prime numbers in the above manner.

Comment: The problem is that this set, unlike the others isn't closed under addition. It does form a group under multiplication, which is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore, in an algebraic context, if $p$ is a prime number and $m$ a positive integer, there really is no reason to pick $\sqrt[m]p$ for $p^{1/m}$ -- the other roots of $X^m-p$ are just as valid. If we add these to our set, and consider the field it generates, we get an abelian closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user3257842, yes, you are correct, a product of radicals can be represented as a single radical, but I really can't find much literature on the "set of radicals", and the properties of this set, only basic math stuff.

Comment: @Mastrem, yes, I understand that adding two radical numbers may result in a number that is not a radical number, the reason I got into this is that using [GNU MPRIA](https://www.gnu.org/software/mpria/) for interval rational arithmetic sometimes gives me rational numbers with very large integers, and radical numbers could be an alternative, as much of the arithmetic operations I'm doing are multiplication and exponentiation, and far fewer are addition and subtraction.

Comment: @Arc By your second question about redundancies, do you mean if there exist numbers with more than one representation? Because these don't exist. Assume there exist two representations which are equal, and raise to a sufficient power, then use unicity for $\mathbb{Q}$. And while using this set turns multiplication and division into addition and subtraction, so does using (approximations of) logarithms.

Comment: Yes, @Mastrem, that was exactly question 2, thanks for the sketch of a proof by contradiction, it will be important if I ever implement this system. Its for dealing with very high powers and factorials. And yes, logarithms can be a fine alternative too, will think about it.

Comment: I think  you are describing the set of "composite" numbers:
 $\space(\mathbb{N}-\mathbb{P}\space\text{ or }\space
 \mathbb{N} \backslash \mathbb{P})\space $
 and if you chose a symbole like $\mathbb{C}$, you must define it as such to distinquish it from the set of "complex" numbers.

Comment: @poetasis, thanks for the comment, but my questions are more complicated than that, its not about the set of natural numbers that are not primes, but instead of the 'radical set' of numbers, something in between the rationals and the algebraic numbers, the comments above pretty much nailed it.